# Calling constant function from another class object

Tags: c++, function, constants, this, member

Here is the code that i have

```
class A
{
public:
    void Func1() const;
};

class B
{
public:
    A* a;
    void Func2() const
    {
        // do something with 'a'
    }
};

void A::Func1() const
{
    B b;
    b.a = this;
    b.Func2();
}
```

Now obviously this is giving me an error in the line, because I'm trying to convert from const to non-const.

```
b.a = this;
```

Is there any way to call `Func2` without having to cast away the constness of `this`. Since `Func2` is a const function anyways, it will not change `this`.

Comment: You cannot change anything to do with the object when you have a const function.. Either call it const *A a, or remove the const from the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `class B` is always going to work with `*a` as a `const` object then as others have said all it takes is to simply change the declaration to

```
public: const A* a
```

At this point I should mention that the constness of `B::Func2` is a red herring because it has absolutely no relation to the constness of `B::a`. That `B::Func2` is `const` means that it's not allowed to change the value of `a`; however, it *is* allowed to dereference `a` and mutate the resulting object.

Now, if `class B` has both `const` and non-`const` operations with respect to `*a` then your class design needs to change. It would be much better if you switched `class B` to use a `const A* a` as above, and added another `class D : public B` that encapsulates all the mutating operations. In addition, `a` should be hidden behind a property setter; this allows you to do things like

```
class B {
    const A* a;
public:
    void setA(const A* a) { this->a = a; }
    void Func2() const {}
};

class D : public B {
    A* a;
public:
    using B::setA;
    void setA(A* a) { 
        this->a = a;
        static_cast<B*>(this)->setA(const_cast<const A*>(a));
    }
    void Func3() { /* do something to D::a */ }
};
```

With this scheme both `B` and `D` keep independent, suitably typed pointers to the object to be accessed. If `setA` is called on a `B`, or on a `D` with a `const A*` parameter then only `B::a` is set. If `setA` is called on a `D` with an `A*`, then both `B::a` and `D::a` are properly set. This has become possible because by abstracting the member behind a setter you can then overload the setter on the constness of its parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the `A*` as const:

```
class A
{
public:
    void Func1() const;
};

class B
{
public:
    const A* a;
    void Func2() const
    {
        // do something with 'a'
    }
};

void A::Func1() const
{
    B b;
    b.a = this;
    b.Func2();
}
```

Since in `A::Func1`, the `this` pointer is const.

Comment: This solves the problem, but i cant have 'a' as const, because B has other functions that can modify 'a'. I know its a fault with my design, could u suggest a better one.

Answer (score 1):

`Func2` may not change `this`, but `b.a` is not `const` and you're free to change it afterwards. There's no right way to do this, although workarounds exist, such as `mutable` or `const_cast`.

It's the sign of a faulty design.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make the `A *` constant:

```
class B {
public:
    const A *a

...
};
```